# Ruby parse SQL query string into hash

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing

I am trying to parse a SQL query string into a hash. Example:
`field = value AND field2 = value2` becomes `{ field: 'value', field2: 'value2' }`

I have tried `Rack::Utils.parse`, which works great for URL params, but doesn't for SQL query string.

My initial thoughts are to split by `AND, OR` etc and then use `Rack::Utils.parse` recursively.

I was thinking there would be a straightforward way of doing this in Rails, but I haven't found anything yet. Has anyone accomplished this before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
sql_query = 'field = value AND field2 = value2 OR field3 = value3'

def hash_for sql_query
  parts = sql_query.split /(and|or)/i
  parts.map do | p | 
    fv = p.split('=').map &:strip
    { fv[0].to_sym => fv[1] }
  end
end
```